# How can I pass an empty String value to a Date field in Java

Tags: java

I have a scenario in a current java program where if the user enters a certain date (01/01/1900) in an excel Date field I'm supposed to flag that and clear the value out in the database.  In this case since the field is a Date type, I need to pass it to an xml as "" i.e and empty String since I can't just pass null.  I'm getting an error because it is expecting a format of "yyyy-MM-dd" to pass to the xml and not "".  Of course when setting the Date field to a certain value, I can't just pass an empty String in the setVesselDate() method because it will complain saying it must be in so so format.  I have a method that validates the date (handleValidateDate) that returns the sql Date value.

Any recommendation to actually set the date field as "" would be helpful.  Below is the code I have:

```
if (vesselAssignmentObj.getVesselDate().length() > 0) 
{
    String clearOutDateFlag = "1900-01-01";
    String clearField = "";
    //below returns a dateformat of yyyy-MM-dd at i
    vesselDate = handleValidateDate(vesselAssignmentObj.getVesselDate(), VESSEL_ASSIGNMENTS_VESSEL, i);

    if (vesselDate.toString().equals(clearOutDateFlag))
    {
        vesselAssignmentObj.setVesselDate(String.valueOf(vesselDate.toString().equals(clearField)));
    }
    else
    {
        vesselAssignmentObj.setVesselDate(String.valueOf(vesselDate).toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Try setting the value of the date to 0000-00-00, this usually works (never tried it in this scenario but everywhere else it always worked for me).

Comment: @AlonAlexander ah if only.  My program (which I did not create but inherited) has to have a check to make sure it is over the year 1900...strange but true.

Comment: does that mean you actually need to set date (im asking because setting it to `null` is not that big of a deal)? if so, you won't be able to set it as an empty string. one possible workaround could be setting the date far far in the future, but this is not what I'd recommend.

Comment: @peech On the contrary, setting a value to NULL in a database is very *big* deal. Nulls raise ambiguities about whether value is missing or intentionally blank. Nulls affect sorting and queries. Nulls have ramifications in the app and in various libraries.

Answer (score 0):

No easy answer.

> … I'm supposed to flag that and clear the value out in the database…

Whoever instructed you should have defined what "clear the value out" means.

## NULL

Usually in a database "clear the value out" might mean using a [NULL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)) value. But nulls bring [a bag of hurt](http://just%20a%20bag%20of%20hurt), raising ambiguity as to the meaning, affecting sorting and queries in various ways, and carrying ramifications in your app(s) and libraries.

While I generally avoid NULL like the plague (taking [Dr. Chris Date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_J._Date)’s advice), this may in fact be the best fit for your needs.

## Arbitrary date as flag

You could choose an arbitrary date to use as flag that means 'empty' or 'not specified' or 'unknown'. But what date? One commenter suggested `0000-00-00` but this value may exceed the limits of some database’s date data-types. Furthermore, dates around year zero can be problematic because of how different calendaring systems handle the meaning of that period. Furthermore, any date before the adoption of the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) in the West is problematic as we lost some days in transitioning from [Julian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar) to Gregorian.

### `1901-01-01`

In a comment you said that a business rules requires dates to be over the year 1900. In that case I would choose `1901-01-01` as my flag date. The trick is making this clear to the entire team and to posterity. Be sure to use well-named constant in your programming, and document well in both your apps and in the database.

### `1970-01-01`

Another common choice of arbitrary date flag is the first of 1970, `1970-01-01`. That date is a commonly used [epoch reference date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) used in [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and in java.time. This makes that particular date recognizable to many folks in the information trade. But you still need to document thoroughly, as this epoch date is far from the only one: At least a [couple dozen other epoch dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) have been in widespread usage.

### Millenium

Yet another choice could be the date of the new millennium. Unfortunately, that phrase means different dates to different people, in year 2000 or 2001.

The Postgres database uses `2000-01-01` as its epoch. The Apple [Cocoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_(API)) framework, possibly the most widely distributed software in the world, uses `2001-01-01`.

## Use objects, not strings

You should not be passing strings to/from your database. Use objects instead. The job of your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) is to mediate between your Java data types and your database types.

Drivers compliant with JDBC 4.2 and later should be able to use [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) types via `PreparedStatement::setObject` and `ResultSet::getObject`. If not, fall back to using the [java.sql](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) types briefly and immediately convert to/from the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) types. To convert, look to new methods added to the old classes.

All this JDBC date-time stuff has been covered many times already, so search Stack Overflow for more information. Search for class names `Instant`, `ZonedDateTime`, and `ZoneId`.